# merge two similar selects remove duplicate by two fileds

Tags: mysql

I have 2 selects returns this fields. 
SELECT 1:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| serviceID | modelID | price |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  1        | 100     |   0   |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  2        | 100     |   0   |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  1        | 200     |   0   |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  2        | 200     |   0   |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

SELECT 2

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| serviceID | modelID | price |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  1        | 100     |   499 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

I need result like this:

```
+-----------+---------+-------+
| serviceID | modelID | price |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  1        | 100     |   499 |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  2        | 100     |   0   |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  1        | 200     |   0   |
+-----------+---------+-------+
|  2        | 200     |   0   |
+-----------+---------+-------+
```

i.e. all from select 1 but if select 2 have fld replace from select1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.serviceID, A.modelID, IF(B.price IS NULL, A.price, B.price) AS price
FROM table1 A LEFT JOIN table2 B ON
A.serviceID = B.serviceID AND A.modelID= B.modelID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
( select 2 here ) union ( select 1 here ) ) as r group by serviceID, modelID
```

this works for me. Probably it'll help somebody.